# How center correctly the image on the header appBar

Tags: react-native, styles

I'm new in react native so i don't know much how render certain things.

[image]

The logo image is not centered correctly. I am not using dependencies for the header just "`<view>`"

I need center the image without affect the icon position on the header bar.

This is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, } from 'react-native';

const logo = require("../../../../src/common/assets/appBar.png");
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";



const CustomAppBar = (props) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.rowContainer} >
                <Icon name="menu"  style={styles.iconStyle} />
            <Image source={logo}  style={styles.imageProperties} ></Image>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
        flex: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#ABD337',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center'
    },

    imageProperties: {
        height: 60,
        flex: 1,
        scaleX:0.5,
        scaleY:0.5,
        marginRight: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center'
    },

    rowContainer:{
        flex: 0,
        paddingTop:0,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: 420,
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
    },

    iconStyle: {
        fontSize: 28,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        paddingLeft: 25,
        textAlignVertical: 'center',
        textAlign:'center',
        height: "100%",
        alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',

    },
});

CustomAppBar.defaultProps = {
    title: "",
};

export { CustomAppBar as default };
```

if is necessary a dependency. What should i use?

Answer (score 2):

Use `justify-content: space-between` on `rowContainer` and add `flex: 1` inside `iconStyle` and `imageProperties`

Answer (score 0):

For aligning the icon and the text near that to **center** use,

```js
justify-content:center;
flex:1;
```